# Add functionality to JQuery UI Datepicker to keep date bofore change

Tags: jquery, user-interface, datepicker, extend

I need to add functionality to JQuery UI Datepicker.

I need to keep current (previous) datepicker date before date changes and set new function method to datepicker to tell if previous date < next date or previous date > next date.

For example I would like to have:

```
$("#myInput").datepicker.("getDirection"); // => 'left' if previous date < next date or => 'right' if previous date > next date
```

Answer (score 1):

Finaly I have found the solution myself :)

```
$.extend($('#mydatepicker').datepicker, {previousDate: null, getDirection: function(){

  var delta = $('#mydatepicker').datepicker("getDate") - $('#mydatepicker').datepicker.previousDate;
  if(delta == 0){
    return 'none';
  }
  if(delta > 0){
    return 'up';
  }
  if(delta < 0){
    return 'down';
  }

}});

$('#mydatepicker').datepicker({
  beforeShow: function(input, inst){
    $('#mydatepicker').datepicker.previousDate = $('#mydatepicker').datepicker("getDate");
});
```